# error "invalid command name \"/usr/bin/perl\" in expect script

Tags: expect

I'm trying to add a one line perl command in to an expect script.

For purposes of this thread, I've boiled my script down to 2 lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

/usr/bin/perl -i -pe 's/\015/\012/g' 'test.txt'
```

If I execute just the perl line in the Terminal (Mac), it runs fine. However, my expect script yields the error

```
 error "invalid command name \"/usr/bin/perl\"
```

I am a novice at shell scripts. hopefully this is an easy solution, but expect documentation seems sparse on the web.

My other option is to just keep the 2 scripts separate.

Comment: never mind. I abandoned expect, it works fine now.

Comment: Just remember that expect is not the shell, it's a different language entirely. Just as Perl has the `system` command, expect has the `exec` command.

Answer (score 0):

Expect is a superset of Tcl. What you need is the [exec command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/exec.htm). To execute your command in a subshell and store the result, you would use a construct like this:

```
set result [exec /usr/bin/perl -i -pe 's/\015/\012/g' test.txt]
```